# JWT with C# with generic repository pattern

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, automapper

A colleague of mine and I have been working on a school project and we ran into a problem with adding a JWT token to our webservice. We tried to recreate a tutorial but we are using the generic repository pattern with a unit of work class. The tutorial we were trying to recreate is [this one by Jason Watmore](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/14/aspnet-core-3-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management). However, to stay true to the repository pattern we didn't see much sense in creating a IUserService and UserService when there is already a UserRepository which essentially aims to do the same thing. Our UserRepository now looks like this:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(JellyContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        public JellyContext DbContext
        {
            get { return _context as JellyContext; }
        }

        public User Create(User user, string password)
        {
            // validation
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                throw new AppException("Password is required");

            if (_context.Users.Any(x => x.Username == user.Username))
                throw new AppException("Username " + "user.Username "+ "is already taken");

            byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            _context.Users.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return user;
        }

        public User Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                return null;

            User user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

            // check if username exists
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            // check if password is correct
            if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
                return null;

            // authentication successful
            return user;
        }

        private static bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] storedHash, byte[] storedSalt)
        {
            if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be empty or whitespace only string.", "password");
            if (storedHash.Length != 64) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length of password hash (64 bytes expected).", "passwordHash");
            if (storedSalt.Length != 128) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length of password salt (128 bytes expected).", "passwordHash");

            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(storedSalt))
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != storedHash[i]) return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be empty or whitespace only string.", "password");

            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> getProjectsFromUser(int userId)
        {
            List<UserProject> uP = await DbContext.Set<UserProject>().Where(c => c.FKEY_User == userId).ToListAsync();

            IList<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

            foreach (UserProject item in uP)
            {
                Project project = await DbContext.Set<Project>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ID == item.FKEY_Project);
                if (project != null)
                {
                    projects.Add(project);
                }
            }
            return projects;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Hour>> getHoursFromUser(int userId)
        {
            return await DbContext.Set<Hour>().Where(c => c.FKEY_User == userId).ToListAsync();
        }

        //example method implementation:
        //public IEnumerable<User> GetUserHours(int id){
        //     return DbContext.User.Where(x => x.Irgendwas == soundsowoascheh);
        //}
    }
```

The implementation in the UserController looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel model)
        {
            User user = _unitOfWork.User.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);

            if (user == null) return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });


            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.ID.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return Ok(new
            {
                ID = user.ID,
                Username = user.Username,
                Email = user.Email,
                Token = tokenString
            });
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public IActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterModel model)
        {
            // map model to entity
            var user = _mapper.Map<User>(model);

            try
            {
                // create user
                //_unitOfWork.User.Create(user, model.Password);
                _unitOfWork.User.Create(user, model.Password);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (AppException ex)
            {
                // return error message if there was an exception
                return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

The solution does not compile but throw an error and we are not quite sure why. Our Startup class looks like this:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<JellyContext>(opts => opts.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionString:JellyDB"]));
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            var appSettingSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingSection);

            var appSettings = appSettingSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.User.Get(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });




            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JellyAPI", Version = "v1" });
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "JellyAPI v1");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And the error that is thrown has something to do with the AutoMapper and it says

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to the project using Nuget Package Manager

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: i just tried that but that didn't work it still throws the same error